Tipkit :: TipNSpopover :: In Mac OS application Unable to close the popover when we clicked on cross icon presented in TipNSpopover view
By implementing the Tipkit framework in the Mac OS application, we were unable to close the popover when we clicked on the cross icon presented in TipNSPopover View.
And anyone please guide me for implementing the TipNSPopover on mouse Handover of NSCollectionview ?. When the mouse enters any of the collection View cells, I have to present the TipNSPopover View.
While click on cross button on TipNSPopover, it not getting closed and unable to achieve showing the TipNSPopover on mouse handover of NScollection View.
I have tried below code, but it not working.
tipObservationTask = tipObservationTask ?? Task { @MainActor in
for await shouldDisplay in sampleTip.shouldDisplayUpdates {
            if shouldDisplay {
                tipPopover = TipNSPopover(sampleTip)
                tipPopover?.show(relativeTo: btnTip.bounds, of: btnTip, preferredEdge: .minY)
            }
            else {
                tipPopover?.close()
                tipPopover = nil
            }
          }
       }
    }

When I tried with button action,I have added two buttons for "show" and "cancel" below code then it working.
@IBAction func showTipNSPopover(_ sender: Any)
{
    tipPopover = TipNSPopover(sampleTip)
    tipPopover?.show(relativeTo:btnTip.bounds, of: btnTip, preferredEdge: .minY)
}
@IBAction func cancelTipNSPopover(_ sender: Any) {
    tipPopover?.close()
    tipPopover = nil
}


Post the code you tried please.

Hi @Willeke I have pasted the code, which I have tried.
